# Vscode Do not apply Trim Trailing Whitespace to specific files only

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use vscode.
Checking Trim Trailing Whitespace in the Vscode settings will remove the trailing blank space.
I would like to exclude this setting for certain files only.

Comment: specific file or specific file type ?

Comment: I want to exclude files in a specific hierarchy.

Comment: specific directory

Comment: not sure if this will work, but you may try to create a .vscode/settings.json file under the folder you want to exclude, and set the proper settings inside it. Homefully vscode will handle this folder as a workspace and apply specific settings

Comment: Do you mean creating two settings.json files in the project?

Comment: one in your actual project root. Another one in the folder you want to have specific behavior